# Efficient way to translate an application

Tags: vb.net, dictionary, translation

So i have developed an application in vb.net but recently i came across the requisite of allowing multiple languages for it. I dont know if there is any 'common' way of doing this kind of things, but my approach to accomplish that is the following:

- I'll need to search in the code for components, error messages and everything that is displayed in the GUI of the application to be translated.
- Secondly i will create a class in which i'll store in memory a dictionary of everything that will be translated
- after, i'll replace the stuff to be translated withing an entry of the dictionary
- then when the application start i'll load the dictionary
- later on, i'll replace the static dictionary and will load it in memory from the database

So for example, my dictionary class:

```
Dim dictionary As New Dictionary(Of String, String)
dictionary.Add("00011", "hello there!")
```

Somewhere in my code i'll replace:

```
mylabel.text = "hello there!"
```

With:

```
mylabel.text = dictionary.item("00011")
```

Later on i will, instead of having a static dictionary, create that dictionary getting the information from a database like this (and load it at the start of the application:

```
_______________________________________
word_code ### word_EN      ### word_FR
_______________________________________
00011     ### hello there  ### bonjour il
```

I will load the dictionary considering which language is selected.

I'm not very confortable with this approach and i have no idea if this is the right thing to do, but if so i have a couple of questions:

- is a dictionary the best data-structure to do so?
- will this be memory-heavy considering i'll have 1000 entries, 1m entries or 10m entries?
- is there any logic and faster way of accomplish the same?

Thank you so much in advanced,
J

Comment: Resources are there for that. It's already built-in and you can always copy/paste the resources file in excel for easy translation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a common way of doing it - having a system name along side a language code being used to look up a translated value. However, generally speaking I'd only advice you to do this for something like system texts and smaller text segments.

The reason is that in for example CMS/ecommerce systems, pages with lots of text likely will need to be translated in a data model to support it to begin with; and then you already have the language division. 
So in that situation, you're better off making a page structure with a translated data model where the detail will be language specific per language for your current website.
For example, you'll have a product -> product_detail where detail keeps the translated values for said product. Similar for article -> article_detail and so on.

But for general translations and system texts which needs to be displayed, it's a common way to do it.
And as you suggest yourself, structures like like dictionary would be a good structures to to make fast look ups and can be cached in the system so you do not need to retrieve them all the time.

Some ways you can expand on it, is by sub dividing your translations into sub groups; say you have an order page and a product page. Then you can have translations assigned to "product" and to "order" with a "common" group as well. 
It will also make it easier to build smaller cache objects, extract less data from your data storage etc, so a page which only revolves around orders don't need to worry about product translations.

It will require memory, but unless you put entire CMS systems into the translations, it should be "minor". 
I would however question a need of 10 million entities of translations and wonder whether or not your system actually requires that many and if it does, then maybe consider an alternate approach and whether it might be better to make multiple versions of the "page" to eliminate the need for translations.

I would also advice you to not use "00011" as a system code to begin, and go for a more "readable" version (like "hello") to ease the readability and maintainability of your code. Then if you want a 'system value' which is like "00011", it's easy to do a search/replace.

Comment: i like your answer better than the suggested in my post. Why? Because i need it to be fully-independent from the client application. My application is already reading from an outside database. Why? Because i can easily correct/change the translation without having to go to the local computer to change the resource files or add things. The suggestion of readable keys might not work for a reason. First, sometimes sentences like error messages need to be translated, in that case, i will need to use only one word to be used as key for that sentence.

Comment: secondly, i have best control over duplicates by using a code number rather than a word number. what do you think?

Comment: The control of duplicates would be the same in my opinion, especially if using dictonaries (only one key allowed) and/or storing the translations in a database to begin with (unique keys). It's just that it's easier to maintain code which has a GetText("Hello") than GetText("000011") - and then as said - you can always do a search/replace once done.